# how to ignore '0' while comparing two value of the list in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, compare, comparison, string-comparison

consider 
value of merge(i).MessageNumber=756 and 
the value of merge(j).MessageNumber1=0756  while comparing this two value..

how to ignore '0' from 0756 in vb.net?

Suggest me/Help me..

currently comparing like -

```
If(merge(i).MessageNumber = merge1(j).MessageNumber1) Then
   Console.WriteLine("all fileds matched")
```

Comment: Are all the values going to represent numbers?  If so then convert them to actual numbers and compare those. Alternatively, you can call `TrimStart` to remove leading '0' characters.

Comment: TrimStart will effect only the string start with 0 rt? not in middle 0?

Comment: Yes. It only trims the start

Comment: The clue is in the name. The proof is in the documentation. You don't need to ask us a question if you can find the answer in the documentation and/or test for yourself very easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Cint(merge(i).MessageNumber) = Cint(merge1(j).MessageNumber1) Then Console.WriteLine("all fileds matched")
```

Comment: this is what you sould do

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TrimStart` to remove specified characters at the start of the string.

```
If(merge(i).MessageNumber.TrimStart("0"c) = merge1(j).MessageNumber1.TrimStart("0"c)) Then
```

But I would suggest that if the property is a number then treat it as a number and the leading zero won't be a problem.

Comment: Actually it is a number,  get a data of  MessageNumber from 1st excel sheet and get another data of MessageNumber from 2nd excel sheet than i'm compare both if same i'm going to print in 3rd excel sheet.

Comment: So why do String comparison when you could be doing Integer comparison?

Comment: oh... if it is number , thn below code is enough rt? 
   CInt((merge(i).MessageNumber = merge1(j).MessageNumber1))

Comment: If it has a leading '0' then it's not a number. A `String` that contains digit characters is still a `String`.